# Cannot logout and login as a different Facebook user in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I implemented social media logins like Facebook,google,twitter  using fire-base and ionic 3 with the following link reference.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova.

first time i successfully log in with my Facebook account credentials and when i logged out using firebase.auth().signOut() and try to login with different Facebook account, instead of showing login screen in the browser it automatically logged in with previous Facebook account details that I just logged out.

same issue for the all the social media logins. I want the browser to show the login page every time for Facebook instead of automatic login.
Please help me out to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that once the user logs in with Facebook, they remain logged in with that same Facebook account. `firebase.auth().signOut()` will sign out the user from the current app using Firebase but not from Facebook. This is normally OK as users usually have one Facebook account on a device but if you insist, here is one option:

Allow the user to re-authenticate by passing the custom parameter to Facebook: `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider().setCustomParameters({auth_type: 'reauthenticate'})` This will show the user the current Facebook account and ask them to enter their password again. This gives them the ability to change the account if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

You may implement "logout" option

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps

Comment: it is not issue with fire-base broswerTab automatically taking the previously entered details.

Comment: if you are reffering to the browserTab cordova plugin - please edit your question because this information is missing